# Problemas com método de verificação de internet no Android

Tags: android

Tenho esse método para verificar se o dispositivo está conectado. Porém estou recebendo algumas msgs de problemas com sincronização dos meus dados. E estou achando que deve ter sido esta alteração no método de verificação de internet. Não sou experiente, por isso preferi vir perguntar para saber se neste método existe algo errado ou que falte. Obrigado.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable (Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected() && activeNetworkInfo.isAvailable();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu costumo usar estes dois métodos para garantir que está conectado a uma rede e que está rede possua internet.

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if( netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
        Log.d("Utils","Esta conectado em um rede!");
        if( isInternetAvailable()){
            Log.d("Utils","Possui internet na rede!");
            return true;
        }else{
            Log.e("Utils","Não possui internet na rede!");
        }
    }
    Log.e("Utils","Não está conectado na rede!");
    return false;
}
```

---

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
        return !ipAddr.equals("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: eu vou testar com algumas coisas que você mandou, para ver se resolve o problema. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Fala aí ;)

Esse método te retorna um booleano dizendo se está ou não com internet no smart.

Espero que ajude.

---

```
public boolean checkOnlineState() {
        ConnectivityManager CManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo NInfo = CManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (NInfo != null && NInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

if(checkOnlineState()){
   // tem internet
}else{
   // nao tem internet             
}
```